# How to create a Toeplitz matrix from a vector?

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, python, toeplitz-matrices

I have to create a Toeplitz matrix of a suitable form from a given vector

The vector is $\left( x[0],x[1],x[2], \dots, x[L-1] \right)$. The matrix is of the form 
 \begin{bmatrix}x[0]&x[1]&x[2]&...&x[L-1]\\x[1]&x[0]&x[2]&...&x[L-2]\\x[2]&  x[1]&x[0]&...&x[L-3]\\...&...&...&...&...\\x[L-1]&x[L-2]&x[L-3]&...&x[0]\end{bmatrix}

The matrix is a rearrangement of the vector values. How can I create a matrix like this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the python code:

```
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz
toeplitz(vector)
```

this would create the matrix of the above form

Comment: why this post is locked?